# 2.8 Rotate multiple objects around the origin in edit mode?

Tags: python, scripting

for some reason the

```
bpy.ops.transform.rotate
```

code dont take account the pivot point, i dont understand why? 
and its only one part of my problem... in my code :

```
import bpy 

A = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
A.select_set(state=False)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = 'BOUNDING_BOX_CENTER'
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=4.71239, axis=(1, 0, 0), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='ENABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=0.00584779)
```

i need that every object of my selection exept the active object do a rotation of 270* on the x axis while the origin point stay in place, is it possible ?

im on 2.8 by the way
i was trying to use the new multi-mesh-editor function, and this new select code :

```
A.select_set(state=False)
```

instead of the old code

thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

here's the version I had to use in my script to set the pivot point to work in blender 2.80.   by setting the transform to rotatate around the cursor, all objects will rotate around that locations and you can use shift+s to place the cursor.

context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = 'CURSOR'

Comment: could you expand appon this. While that one line may be the answer. It would be much more useful if you for example linked to the documentation, explained what each part of that did, or how this is different from pre 2.8

Comment: sure.  actually.  here's an addon with a gif that explains how I do this:
https://gumroad.com/l/fastpivot